# How to open a file and delete the first item (item at index 0)

Tags: python, python-2.7

Atm I am working on a plug in for a Chat bot for Twitch. 
I have this working so far. So that I am able to add Items to a file.

```
# Variables
f = open("Tank_request_list.txt","a+")
fr = open("Tank_request_list.txt","r")
tr = "EBR" # test input
tank_request = fr.read()
treq = tank_request.split("#")

with open("Tank_request_list.txt") as fr:
    empty = fr.read(1)
    if not empty:
        f.write(tr)
        f.close
    else:
        tr = "#" + tr
        f.write(tr)
        f.close
```

I now need to work out how to delete an item at Index 0

I also have this piece of code I need to implement also:

```
# List Length
list_length = len(treq)
print "There are %d tanks in the queue." % (list_length)

# Next 5 Requests
print "Next 5 Requests are:"
def tank_lst(x):
  for i in range(5):

    print "- " + x[i]

# Run Tank_request    
tank_lst(treq)
```

The following will return the right answer but not write it.

```
def del_played(tank):
    del tank[0]
    return tank

tanks = treq
print del_played(tanks)
```

Comment: Bare in mind I am very new to Python and this is my first ever project.

Comment: Open the file, skip the first item, read the remaining, write to another file, swap previous with new file. How you skip the first item depends on (1) what the item is, (2) how they are written to the file.

Comment: Just truncate the file and write all the contents to it, `f.truncate(); f.write(del_played(tanks))` would do it, I guess

Answer (score 0):

First, remove the content
Use the `truncate`  function for removing the content from a file then write the new list into it.